# how to pass data from controller to custom hooks in codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have a hooks class in my app where I want to send my session data from my controller. but I am having problem passing data. I don't know whether is it possible to send data from controller to hooks.

here is an exampple of an hooks class the code is below

```
function switchUser()
{
    $CI = &get_instance();    
    $user_id=$CI->uid;

    if ($user_id == 'client') {
       echo "hello";
    }   
}
```

here is my controller

```
class Client_Controller extends MX_Controller
{
    public $uid;
    function __construct($dbase=array())
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->uid=$this->session->userdata("uid");
    }
}
```

In hooks.php file, I have the following code

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'function' => 'switchDatabase',
    'filename' => 'switchDatabase.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: use this `$CI->session->userdata("uid")` instead of this `$CI->uid` in your switchUser method

Comment: Thank you very much prodeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*In your `switchUser` method*

use this

```
$CI->session->userdata("uid")
```

Instead of this

```
$CI->uid
```

Whole code should be like this :

```
function switchUser()
{
    $CI = &get_instance();    
    $user_id = $CI->session->userdata("uid") 

    if ($user_id == 'client') {
       echo "hello";
    }   
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html